I am not able to install any extension using the extension manager in Lubuntu 24.04
I am not able to install any extension using the extension manager in Lubuntu 24.04.
When I open an extension in extension manager I get this error:
    Support Log
----
Version: 0.5.0
Package Format: Unknown Package
Status: Third Party
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
GTK: 4.14.2
Libadwaita: 1.5.0
----
Could not check for updates: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.527 was not provided by any .service files

I tried reinstalling but it didn't work.

So you're talking about GNOME Shell Extensions? Obviously GNOME isn't the stock desktop environment in Lubuntu (otherwise we'd call it Gubuntu?). So we'd need a little bit more clarity on the specifics of your particular set up. However, it does beg the question: why not just use Ubuntu where it's built around GNOME as opposed to Lubuntu where it is not?

Your question makes no sense, Lubuntu uses the LXQt desktop; a Qt5 desktop, and not GNOME/GTK so why are you talking about gnome extensions??  What LXQt extensions are you asking about?  What LXQt extension manager?  I see no reference in the manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/search.html?q=extension&check_keywords=yes&area=default) or in the upstream GitHub wiki either (https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/wiki)   You need to clarify what you're asking about; as GNOME (GTK4) & Lubuntu/LXQt (Qt5) are different systems.

I am really sorry I am very new to linux, the reason I am using lubuntu and not ubuntu is another issue I am facing which may need to be asked separately. Thank you for the help @guiverc

I consider a Lubuntu system a Ubuntu system... ie. I'm using Ubuntu now, but my desktop is LXQt and I'm using a lubuntu session by the Lubuntu team (I & u/wxl are members of that team)... however GNOME & LXQt differ..   My box is a multi-desktop install so I'm rather familiar with multiple desktops installed (& sometimes complications), but your question needs to be clear with details. Lubuntu & GNOME differ.

please have a look on this question link @guiverc
